# Does $\forall x \exists y (P(x) \land Q(y))$ imply $\forall x P(x)$?

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers

I am not sure if the $x$ in $\forall x \exists y (P(x) \land Q(y))$ carries some kind of "context" from the $\exists y$ that would make $\forall x P(x)$ not neccesarily true.

Comment: Let $c$ be arbitrary, are you able to deduce $P(c)$ from your hypothesis ?

Comment: Hint: note $\forall x\exists y(P(x))$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quantifying a variable without using it in the quantified statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109900/quantifying-a-variable-without-using-it-in-the-quantified-statement) (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cforall%20x%5Cexists%20y%20P(x)%24&p=1))

Comment: I'd say its closer to prenex normal form than null quantification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c$ be arbitrary. Then by the hypothesis we get

$$\exists y[P(c)\land Q(y)]
$$
Hence we get $$P(c)\land Q(d)$$ for some $d$.
Hence we get $P(c)$. Since $c$ is arbitrary, thus we get $\forall xP(x)$

Comment: It was a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that follows.  First, here are some relevant equivalence principles:

**Prenex Laws**

Where $\varphi$ is any formula and where $x$ is *not* a free variable in $\psi$:

$ \forall x \ \varphi \land \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi \land \psi)$

$  \psi \land \forall x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \land \varphi)$

$ \exists x \ \varphi \land \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi \land \psi)$

$  \psi \land \exists x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \land \varphi)$

$ \forall x \ \varphi \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\varphi \lor \psi)$

$  \psi \lor \forall x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \forall x (\psi \lor \varphi)$

$ \exists x \ \varphi \lor \psi \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\varphi \lor \psi)$

$  \psi \lor \exists x \ \varphi  \Leftrightarrow \exists x (\psi \lor \varphi)$

So with those (well, the first and third):

$$\forall x \exists y (P(x) \land Q(y))$$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\forall x (P(x) \land \exists y \ Q(y))$$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\forall x \ P(x) \land \exists y \ Q(y)$$

And clearly, this last statement implies $\forall x \ P(x)$